# Invalid JNI reference (calling Java method from c++)

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm having a problem with a call to enable the GPS localization from c++. I generated the JNI wrappers with SWIG. The logcat says :

```
01-02 17:14:03.816: D/dalvikvm(6165): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.swig/lib/libcppinterface.so 0x44e7ebf0
01-02 17:14:03.976: D/dalvikvm(6165): Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.swig/lib/libcppinterface.so 0x44e7ebf0
01-02 17:14:04.886: W/dalvikvm(6165): JNI WARNING: 0x44e8bb48 is not a valid JNI reference
01-02 17:14:04.886: W/dalvikvm(6165):              in Lcom/example/swig/cpplib/cppinterfaceJNI;.LocationSpotter_refresh (JLcom/example/swig/cpplib/LocationSpotter;)V (CallVoidMethodV)
01-02 17:14:04.886: I/dalvikvm(6165): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-02 17:14:04.886: I/dalvikvm(6165):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
01-02 17:14:04.886: I/dalvikvm(6165):   | sysTid=6165 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
01-02 17:14:04.886: I/dalvikvm(6165):   | schedstat=( 226108400 549900071 66 )
01-02 17:14:04.886: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at com.example.swig.cpplib.cppinterfaceJNI.LocationSpotter_refresh(Native Method)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at com.example.swig.cpplib.LocationSpotter.refresh(LocationSpotter.java:56)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at com.example.swig.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-02 17:14:04.896: I/dalvikvm(6165):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 17:14:04.906: E/dalvikvm(6165): VM aborting
```

I trigger the call from Java with this line :

```
LocationSpotter.getLocationSpotter().refresh();
```

getLocationSpotter() triggers in c++ this code which creates a jobject (jSpotter) :

```
// Retrieve the current JNIEnv* with the cached JVM
JNIEnv* env;
AndroidLocationSpotter::cachedJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/swig/AndroidLocationSpotter");
jmethodID construct = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "()V");

jSpotter = env->NewObject(clazz, construct);
```

and after the method refresh() triggers this code which makes the application crash :

```
// Retrieve the current JNIEnv* with the cached JVM
JNIEnv* env;
AndroidLocationSpotter::cachedJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/swig/AndroidLocationSpotter");
jmethodID refresh = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "refresh", "()V");

env->CallVoidMethod(jSpotter, refresh); // The line where the crash happens
```

I also need to mention that I initiate "cachedJVM" in the JNI_OnLoad function. Hope someone could help me on this, thanks

**EDIT**

Working code :

```
// Retrieve the current JNIEnv* with the cached JVM
JNIEnv* env;
AndroidLocationSpotter::cachedJVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/example/swig/AndroidLocationSpotter");
jmethodID construct = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "<init>", "()V");

jSpotter = env->NewObject(clazz, construct);

jSpotter = env->NewGlobalRef(jSpotter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new global reference using the returned `jSpotter` reference.  The reference you are currently using is local to your current frame, and will go out of scope (probably when you DetachCurrentThread()).

You need to call `env->NewGlobalRef(jSpotter)` or `env->NewWeakGlobalRef(jSpotter)` (both of which have corresponding `free` functions) and use the reference returned.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of proper attach/detach handling (assuming you don't need the thread for further Java operations):

```
  JNIEnv* env;
  JavaVM* jvm = AndroidLocationSpotter::cachedJVM;

  int attached = jvm->GetEnv((void *)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) == JNI_OK;
  if (!attached) {
    if (jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void *)&env, NULL) != JNI_OK) {
      // Attach failed, handle error condition
      return;
    }
  }

  // Pushing a frame ensures proper cleanup of any local references you might generate
  // in your JNI code, e.g. with NewLocalRef (optional)                                                                                                                                                                                
  if (env->PushLocalFrame(16) < 0) {
    // Handle failed frame push error
  }
  else {
    // example local reference generation: ref2 = env->NewLocalRef(ref);

    //
    // Perform your primary Java operations here
    //

    env->PopLocalFrame(NULL);
  }

  if (!attached) {
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
  }
```

Comment: Hmm ok I'm gonna test that tomorrow. By the way I never call DetachCurrentThread, should I ?

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help. For those that are facing the same issue, after putting `env->NewGlobalRef(jSpotter);` in my code, I had another problem when running the app on my device (apparently because of ICS). You should instead write `jSpotter = env->NewGlobalRef(jSpotter);`. Check the edit to see thoses changes